# Testing self-generated RSA public key in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rsa, pem, asn.1

I've generated a [PKCS#1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017) RSA keypair using a program I wrote. I've output public key as DER encoding of the `RSAPublicKey` ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` data structure.

However, when I try to use it in the OpenSSL `pkeyutl` and `rsautl` commands, OpenSSL says

> `unable to load Public Key`

I've tried both DER and PEM formats.

Is there additional encoding and/or data structure that I must apply for it to be usable in OpenSSL?

Here's my command line:

```sh
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -in 128-bit.dat -inkey rsa-1440-pub.pem
```

```sh
openssl rsautl -in 128-bit.dat -encrypt -keyform PEM -pubin -inkey rsa-1440-pub.pem
```

The public key data structure in PEM format

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIG9AoG1AMuWjPN12DBObfQCxRVKLnP51BbFyEZeSJrmU3bPnwMv8S7hz0dGcSCA
Wa/EZWbNx8gLiWkHlcXeHC+8UO4rtOuaE9PhOXM819C8Y84Y8SddQ4RUMmj1y8ph
pBwExHDiSuKmbvFQLcB7uG10ZUFA9Q5bq/o6bNGsbTas/oB8TzSox5w66maDeyMc
cQFRko2/4AduuStYpnvi8eXa6kaAVDQ43NPCcdep0p78SKjYJNKu8WyZvwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a public key to be accepted by OpenSSL, it appears that you need to wrap it in a [`SubjectPublicKeyInfo`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1) data structure. Like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIHTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4HBADCBvQKBtQDLlozzddgwTm30AsUVSi5z+dQW
xchGXkia5lN2z58DL/Eu4c9HRnEggFmvxGVmzcfIC4lpB5XF3hwvvFDuK7TrmhPT
4TlzPNfQvGPOGPEnXUOEVDJo9cvKYaQcBMRw4kripm7xUC3Ae7htdGVBQPUOW6v6
OmzRrG02rP6AfE80qMecOupmg3sjHHEBUZKNv+AHbrkrWKZ74vHl2upGgFQ0ONzT
wnHXqdKe/Eio2CTSrvFsmb8CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```